# please help me resolve find what method gives me a result for this

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

I have this mathematic problem: (124164a/300b/2360/.85)+(124164a/25b/2360/.85)+(124164a/55b/2360/.85)=3.81=(a/b/2360/.85)

And this is the result:
a≈87.4514, b≈0.0114422

I payed for WolframAlpha Pro just to get this problem solved and understand how it worked and did not get an understanding after expanding, would love to have someone tell me how Wolfram got this result.

Comment: There are two equations with two unknowns: `(124164 a/300 b/2360/.85) + (124164 a/25 b/2360/.85) + (124164 a/55 b/2360/.85) == 3.81` and `3.81 == (a/b/2360/.85)` Solve the second equation for `a` in terms of `b`. Plug that solution into the first equation and solve the revised equation for `b`. Plug the value of `b` into the initial solution for `a` to get the value of `a`. There are two solutions: `{a -> -87.4514, b -> -0.0114422}` and `{a -> 87.4514, b -> 0.0114422}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.